# Python printing thrice while I called the function twice, why is this so?

Tags: python

I am new in python and I was trying to understand how does self work. As I came from JavaScript I think its bit similar to this. If I am wrong please correct me. In the meantime I wrote this code:

```
class Restaurant(object):
   bankrupt = False

   def open_branch(self):
        if not self.bankrupt:
            print("branch opened")

x = Restaurant()
y = Restaurant()
y.bankrupt = True

print(y.open_branch())

print(x.open_branch())
```

and got the output:

```
None
branch opened
None
```

As I called the open_branch() twice. It should not print thrice. I think it should print,

```
branch opened   // for first call
None           // for 2nd call
```

[you could paste the code here and see](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php)
Please somebody explain this.

Comment: Youre printing the return value of the function which is none

Comment: You're calling *print*  thrice

Comment: Worth noting this would print 3 times in JS as well.

Comment: i really dont get it. where am i calling thrice ? i just wrote print print(y.open_branch())
&&
print(x.open_branch())

Comment: Are you using any framework like django etc?

Comment: No.. printing in pycharm.

Comment: `print("branch opened")` — `print(y.open_branch())` — `print(x.open_branch())` — That's three.

Comment: You have called the print thrice

Comment: What you _probably_ meant to do is `return "branch opened"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you have the following code:

```
class Restaurant(object):
    bankrupt = False

    def open_branch(self):
        if not self.bankrupt:
            print("branch opened")

x = Restaurant()
y = Restaurant()
```

till here you have two objects of type 'Restaurant'.

```
y.bankrupt = True
```

Here you changed the attribute `bankrupt` of the object stored in the variable `y`

```
print(y.open_branch())
```

This will output

```
None
```

only; why? Well first of all you are calling the function `y.open_branch()` but this function will not output anything because the attribute `bankrupt` is true so `if not self.bankrupt` is evaluated to false and thus the print statement is not executed. However the function `open_branch()` is also not returning anything (there is no `return true` statement or so. So `print(y.open_branch())` is equal to `print(None)` which will output `None`. Next

```
print(x.open_branch())
```

For x the attribut `bankrupt` is false, so `if not self.bankrupt` is true and the print statement `print("branch opened")` will get evaluated. Afterwards `None` will be outputted for the same reason as why `None`got outputted by `print(y.open_branch())`.

Comment: i got it now. actually this if not made me puzzled. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The two print statements at the end are only printing the **returned** results of the method:

```
print(y.open_branch())
print(x.open_branch())
```

Since python returns `None` by default if you don't explicitly specify a return statement, and you are calling the methods twice, then it's expected that you see two `None` statements.

If you call the method without print, you will see a **single** printed message.

```
y.open_branch()
x.open_branch()
```

---

You could improve your code by adding return statements within the method and doing the print outside, as you are doing right now. Something like

```
class Restaurant(object):
    bankrupt = False

    def open_branch(self):
         if not self.bankrupt:
             return "branch opened"
         return "branch closed"


x = Restaurant()
y = Restaurant() 

y.bankrupt = True

print(y.open_branch())
# output:'branch closed'

print(x.open_branch())
# output: 'branch opened'
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is you're calling `print` on the return value of `open_branch`.

So when you see it print `None`, you're seeing the outcome of `print(x.open_branch()` and `print(y.open_branch()`.

When you see `branch opened`, that's the result of the print *inside* `open_branch`.

Try this:

```
class Restaurant(object):
   bankrupt = False

   def open_branch(self):
        result = ""
        if self.bankrupt:
            result = "Restaurant is bankrupt"
        else:
            result = "Branch opened"
        return result

x = Restaurant()
y = Restaurant()
y.bankrupt = True

print(y.open_branch())
print(x.open_branch())
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that are giving you issues here:

- Your `open_branch` function isn't returning anything, so when you call `print(self.open_branch(x))` it's printing `None`, which is what all functions in Python return by default if there is no `return` statement. You can solve this issue by replacing

  ```
  if not self.bankrupt:
      print("branch opened")
  ```

  with

  ```
  if not self.bankrupt:
      return "branch opened"
  ```
- You're calling `print` three times, which is why you're getting three lines printed on the console (although this will resolve itself if you replace the `print` in the function with the `return` statement I detailed above).
- You should put an `else` statement under your `if` clause, so that it will return something useful (instead of `None` if `self.bankrupt == True`) and you can tell if the branch was opened or not. I'd suggest something like:

  ```
  if not self.bankrupt:
      return "branch opened"
  else:
      return "Restaurant is bankrupt, branch could not be opened"
  ```